# count entries in database

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am new to sqlite for iOS. I am making an app in which user will store the client names in the database according to the day they're appointed.

```
id Day         Client1    Client2    Client3    Client4    Client5    Client6
0  Monday      Nitin      Vijay      Akshay     Ajit       Sahil      Ravi
1  Tuesday     Ravi       Akshay     Nitin      Sahil      Vijay      Ajit    
2  Wednesday   Vijay      Nitin      Vijay      Akshay     Ravi       Ajit
3  Thursday    Akshay     Ajit       Nitin      Ravi       Sahil      Vijay
4  Friday      Nitin      Nitin      Akshay     Sahil      Ravi       Vijay
```

Some clients will be repeated daily, how to count number of times each client has met me and save it to int every day.

eg.

```
Monday
Nitin = 1
Vijay = 1
Akshay = 1
Ajit = 1
Sahil = 1
Ravi = 1
```

This should be updated daily at 12:00AM and if I request database to show the count on Tuesday, it should come with (Count on Monday + Count on Tuesday)

```
Tuesday
Nitin = 2
Vijay = 2
Akshay = 2
Ajit = 2
Sahil = 2
Ravi = 2
```

How should I achieve it?

Comment: What happens if you have seven clients on a day?

Comment: To deal with this problem, I'll be making 10 columns for clients into the database.

Comment: What happens if you have 11 clients on a day?

Comment: Nope, there will not be more than 10 clients / day.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have normalized your database, with tables like these:

```
Days:  id  Day
       0   Monday
       1   Tuesday
       2   Wednesday
       ...

Appointments:  DayID  Client
               0      Nitin
               0      Vijay
               0      Akshay
               0      Ajit
               0      Sahil
               0      Ravi
               1      Ravi
               1      Akshay
               1      Nitin
               ...
```

then you can simply count the records for each client:

```sql
SELECT Client, COUNT(*)
FROM Appointments
WHERE DayID BETWEEN 0 AND 1  -- Monday and Tuesday
GROUP BY Client
```